# Type of Database for Live Streaming

Tags: android, java, sql

I begin with a project about videostreaming with Android, specifically Live Streaming (not video on demand)

The device Android will transmit video and audio, too I will have other software in desktop (development in Java) for from it the user could see the transmition. I still don't know that data base use for this project. I would like to make this project like to Periscope App. Other question, Do you know if exists some app for android open source about live streaming?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! The question-and-answer format of this site works best if you [put each question in a separate question post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/192154). Please [edit] your post down to one question, and create new posts to ask any further questions. You'll get better answers that way. Apart from which: what requirements do you have? A database doesn't "stream video", so the connection is unclear. Please also see: [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)